# send user-uploaded files to s3 in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, heroku, amazon-s3

I have an app where users can upload a csv and then play around with the data. Right now the csv is getting uploaded to my rails app's public folder on heroku but I want to send it to s3 b/c heroku isn't good with user uploaded files. Here's the code in my controller where I'm saving the csv directly to heroku:

```
File.open(Rails.root.join(
  'public', 
  'user_files', 
  csv_name + '.csv'
), 'w') do |file|        
    file.write(output_csv_file)
end
```

How do I alter this code, as well as any other code I need to change in rails, to send this file to my aws bucket in s3? I've installed the 'aws-sdk' gem in my Gemfiles. I've also set the proper environment variables in heroku for my bucket. That's all I've done so far... Really lost.

Comment: How are you uploading the files currently? Is it with `Paperclip`?

Comment: Nope, don't have paperclip. Don't know how to use that. Right now I'm uploading the file through a form. output_csv_file = params[:file].read. Then I write the file to my rails app as shown above.

Comment: Okay thanks for the reply! Let me write an answer for you

Comment: https://github.com/nathancolgate/s3-swf-upload-plugin

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know if this will help, but it may give you some ideas

---

**Paperclip**

The way our team uploads files with Rails is to use the amazing [`Paperclip`](https://github.com/thoughtbot/paperclip) gem. I mention this because not only does Paperclip integrate with S3, but it also gives you a central way to manage your files correctly

Paperclip works with ActiveRecord (your db) to store the file information. You can then define in Paperclip's config options where the files are stored (S3 included). This means that if you're uploading a .csv file & allowing users to change it, using something like Paperclip will help you keep it in order correctly

Although you may or may not benefit from Paperclip, here's an overview of how it works:

---

**Uploading With Paperclip**

There's a good [Railscast about Paperclip here](http://railscasts.com/episodes/134-paperclip)

[image: Paperclip Railscast]

Here's how to get it working:

```
#app/models/csv.rb
class CSV < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_attached_file :attachment

end

#app/controllers/csv_controller.rb
def create
    @csv = CSV.new(CSV_params)
    @csv.save
end

#app/views/csv/new.html.erb
<%= form_for @csv do |f| %>
    <%= f.file_field :attachment %>
<% end %>
```

---

**Using Paperclip with S3**

There is a great [tutorial on Heroku about Paperclip & S3](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/paperclip-s3)

Here is some live code on how to get Paperclip working with S3:

```
#app/config/application.rb -> can use /environments/production.rb if you wish
config.paperclip_defaults = {
    :storage => :s3,
    :s3_host_name => 's3-eu-west-1.amazonaws.com'
}

#app/config/models/csv.rb
has_attached_file :image,
                :styles => { :medium => "x300", :thumb => "x100" },
                :default_url => "http://images.apple.com/iphone-5s/home/images/smart_hero.png",
                :storage => :s3,
                :bucket => 'firststop',
                :s3_credentials => S3_CREDENTIALS
```

This is an overview of how you can get Paperclip working with Rails & S3. If it sounds like something you could benefit from, let me know & we can work to get it implemented in your app